# Css print @page set orientation without eliminating the other one?

Tags: html, css, printing, orientation

`@page {size: landscape}` in CSS will print the page as landscape orientation, awesome, but why will the user lose the ability to chose between landscape and portrait after you define in CSS which one you want the page to use?

At least in Google Chrome that is like it happens.

Can't I set landscape by default, so the user may choose portrait if he judges that's what he needs?

Comment: Can you do something with two stylesheets, one for landscape and one for portrait (with rel=alternate), and let the user choose between those?

Comment: Is that actually possible?

Comment: Well, it won't be straightforward to the user... they must choose the alternate stylesheet first (which won't change anything on the screen) and then print. Not sure how to tell the user they should do this.

Comment: so I think the only way is to leave as landscape.